# How to read firestore GeoPoint in python script?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

I am writing a Python script to read Firebase Firestore data. Somehow documentSnapshop.to_dict() was not working for me. So, I have written a class by referring to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/firestore/cloud-client/snippets.py#L103 this resource.

In my case, there is the location of the city stored as the GeoPoint firestore field. I am not able to get it in the dictionary. How can we add GeoPoint location in the City class mentioned in the reference example mentioned above?

Comment: [Geopoint](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/firestore/index.html) has latituge and longitude parameters. Something like `u'latitude': self.location.latitude` should work I guess.

Comment: @EmilGi Thanks for the comment. Could you please write the 'City class' with your suggestion? The 'City class' you can find in the example I've shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the GeoLocation property is named `location`, you should just add it like:

```
class City(object):
    def __init__(self, name, state, country, capital=False, population=0,
                 regions=[], location):
        self.name = name
        self.state = state
        self.country = country
        self.capital = capital
        self.population = population
        self.regions = regions
        self.location = location
```

Then, when getting data from the DB, you could set the `location` property like this:

```
source = db.collection(u'collection').document(u'docId').get().to_dict()
city = City(source[u'name'], source[u'state'], source[u'country'], source[u'country'], source[u'location'])
```

If you wanted to fetch the latitude or longitude, you could do so with the following code:

```
city.location.latitude
city.location.longitude
```